# Терминал в Linux коверкает названия файлов Google Drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, google-drive

Терминал Linux странно отображает названия файлов в Google Drive.
Если смотреть через проводник, то с названием файлов все в порядке, а в терминале получается нечто подобное:

```
1SjRvK3dhI3toX4ipY4BC0NcPJSLgNKce  1SokyYU1zAwaj1SXQasz7ue7-BJRAWmGe
1Sjyx9SXfiQ0D4YVzYIJ-oOMs_TuyqBiR  1SrZi0mJ0q0SqxNj2PS-pDqmEjkc0vsZq
1SkvAZG3QgzrOycuftXSjtg9hdTDatmUx
```

Это было с самого начала установки системы.
Сейчас ОС Ubuntu 23.04, но такое было и на Fedora.

Comment: Это не баг, а фича. В терминале вы видите настоящие идентификаторы объектов. Проводник извелекает человеко-читаемые имена из метаданных объектов. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ указан Pak Uula - терминал показывает настоящие идентификаторы объектов. А проводник достает названия из метаданных.
В данной ситуации вопрос о целесообразности использования гугл диска для меня на linux полностью решен - нецелесообразно.